# www-data (php) can execute "df -h" command but not completely

Tags: php, bash, apache2

So, I did this "fancy" dashboard, (plain HTML + PHP) which should show how much disk space is left.

```
$df = shell_exec("(df -h)");
echo "<pre>$df</pre>";
```

And I get the output in browser like so:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        59G   23G   34G  41% /
devtmpfs        413M     0  413M   0% /dev
tmpfs           418M  7.3M  411M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           418M     0  418M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           418M   12M  406M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            84M  4.0K   84M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       253M   52M  201M  21% /boot
```

Which seems fine, however, if I do that in terminal:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        59G   23G   34G  41% /
devtmpfs        413M     0  413M   0% /dev
tmpfs           418M  7.3M  411M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           418M   12M  406M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           418M     0  418M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       253M   52M  201M  21% /boot
tmpfs            84M  4.0K   84M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       458G  396G   39G  92% /media/pi/Pi3s_NAS
/dev/mmcblk0p1  486M  117M  370M  24% /media/pi/BOOT
```

As you can see, in browser it lacks everything from /media dir.

Tried to troubleshoot it, found out that by adding `www-data` to `disk` group did pseudo solve it, but not entirely. What I mean by that, is that from now on, when I run command `php /var/www/html/index.php`
I do get the output I expected (previously it did not), however the expected output is still absent from web browser.
Any ideas why it could be like this?

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered this (also on a Pi), but can reproduce the issue with `sudo -u www-data df`, which doesn't output lines under /media/pi.

My permissions on the mountpoint was `r-x` for 'others', but `/media/pi` was owned by `root`, with a long acl list ending in `o::---`.

Adding `u:www-data:r-x` to the csv list fixed the issue for me :·)